# Not able to setup Docker registry with JFrog Artifactory - Docker login fail

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

I am now to JFrog Artifactory. Doing Docker registry setup and having below issue. Please help me on this.

Infrastructure setup:

We have Artifactory install in our datacenter VM. Running on Tomcat port 8082. So if I need to access from localhost. I can just call https://localhost:8082/artifactory ; Again we have URL setup for that in apache server (which indeed doing reverse proxy). URL id: https://dev-tools.xyz.com/artifactory ; which we have our company (xyz) wind card certs.

Docker registry  setup: I went ahead and click on (GUI)  click on “Admin”  Repositories “local”  Click “New”  select Docker (repo type)  Put Repository name “docker-local”  leave all default and save it. Hope at this moment I am all done with setup.

Now I went to my docker server; its different server then my artifactory server. And did…

```
[root@linuxvm1234 ~]# docker login -u adm  -p xxxx https://devtools.xyz.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://devtools.xyz.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

Question.. not sure what is the wrong with this URL?

Comment: This might help: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-UsingaReverseProxy